# On a certain usage of the word "only"

Tags: meaning, history, only

Some documents such as medical prescriptions and cheques employ the word "only" in an interesting manner:

[image]
([Dpbsmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Dpbsmith) via [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Specrx-prescription2.jpg))

On cheques the usage is something like **"Three hundred dollars *only*"**.

The intention seems to be to prevent tampering by making it impossible to alter the original meaning simply by appending text.

My questions:

1. Is this indeed why "only" is used in such contexts?
2. When and where did this practice originate?
3. Where is it still in common use today?

Comment: (1) Yes (on cheques); it's almost a big punctuation mark. But with the prescription form, the usage means 'don't [try to] use these forms for prescribing eyedrops / antibiotics / magnifying glasses ...  (3) It's still quite acceptable, and used, with cheques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word *only*, when placed at the end of a line of text indicating the purpose of an instrument or the amount of a sum of money, seems to have a legally binding restrictive force.

One example in U.S. law relates to endorsements on checks. According to Roger Miller, [*Business Law: Text and Cases*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VUTAAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA242&dq=%22for+deposit+only+and+for+collection+only%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1pQ8VaCCMcTGogTJ1YC4DQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22for%20deposit%20only%20and%20for%20collection%20only%22&f=false) (2014):

> **INDORSEMENTS FOR DEPOSIT OR COLLECTION** A common type of restrictive indorsement makes the indorsee (almost always a bank) a collecting agent of the indorser {UCC 3-206(c)}. In particular, the indorsements “For deposit only” and “For collection only” have the effect of locking the instrument into the bank collection process. Only a bank can acquire the rights of a holder following one of these indorsements until the item has been specially indorsed by a bank to a person who is not a bank {UCC 3-206(c), 4-201(b)}.

One of the earliest instances in a Google Books search of an article where "for deposit only" is recognized as a form of restrictive endorsement is in [*The Banker's Magazine and Statistical Register*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tm49AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA234&dq=%22for+deposit+only%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wI88VZqLDI7aoATwvYHIAQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22for%20deposit%20only%22&f=false) (September 1879):

> In the August number of your magazine I notice in "Inquiries of Correspondents" a query in regard to erroneous indorsements and your answer thereto.
>
> Suppose "C D" had indorsed the check "for deposit," would your answer have been the same?
>
> REPLY.—We think there is a distinction between the to cases. In the former, the indorsement was "For deposit only to my credit," which, being addressed to the drawee bank, restricts the deposit to a credit on its books. But the mere words "For deposit," indorsed or stamped on a check, may be regarded as a memorandum indicating that the check is to be paid through some bank, and not to any bearer who may present it.

The May 1881 issue of [*The Banker's Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CFYmAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA896&dq=%22for+deposit+only%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wI88VZqLDI7aoATwvYHIAQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22for%20deposit%20only%22&f=false) adds this comment:

> The use of these indorsements has increased of late years, and is evidently intended to obviate the danger of loss, which may arise in the ordinary course of business, until a check is safely deposited in the usual channels of collection.

It thus appears that "for deposit only" may be a shortened form of the restrictive endorsement "for deposit only to my credit." Use of that shortened form remains extremely common in U.S. banking today, more than 135 years later.